# Gray image and RGB image size in with opencv after compressed with libjpeg

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, compression, libjpeg

I have 2 different raw image files that I load with opencv and compress with libjpeg.The sizes of the raw images are same.And then for the BGR image:

```
 IpImage* im=cvLoadImage(file_name);

 cvCvtColor(im,im,CV_BGR2RGB);
```

and then compress with libjpeg.

The size of the compressed image is ~= 20000 KB

for the Gray image;

```
 IpImage* im = cvLoadImage(file_name);

 IpImage* im_2;

 im_2=cvCreateImage(size,8,1);

 cvCvtColor(im,im,CV_BGR2RGB);

 cvCvtColor(im,im_2,CV_RGB2GRAY);
```

And then compress im_2.But this time the compressed size is ~=80000 KB

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @aldurdisciple is it normal?

Comment: Yes it may be normal. For instance if one image has large homogeneous areas and the second has a lot of details. However if your two images have very similar contents, there might be something going on.